# Safari automation through Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, safari, automation

I am trying to run my selenium automation tests on safari but I am facing an issue running through Jenkins.

I have a osX env running on a vm and running the tests locally everything is working fine. Its when I try to run these tests through Jenkins that I run into issues. They run but they are unable to open safari.

Im not very familiar with macs so dont really know whats causing the issue. The vm is a slave of jenkins and everything seems ok there.

Thanks for any help.

The error i am seeing is as follows

```
 System info: host: 'Test-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 
'fe80:0:0:0:1c75:5215:5f4d:cef2%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 
'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
 Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:40)
at extra.StartupTestCase.cleanUpLogin(StartupTestCase.java:292)
at extra.StartupTestCase.beforeSuite(StartupTestCase.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1442)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1411)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:16788 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:343)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
... 41 more
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the error stack trace trimmed from the top along with your code trials? Those would have been useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code is a mature java based automation framework which falls over at the following line 
'driver = new SafariDriver():'

I am not specifying the safari driver in the code as from reading up it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error log it seems you haven't set Safari driver for Selenium.
Find out the latest safari driver for Selenium and set it's path in your code.

Running selenium code from Jenkins:

I would suggest you to use a jenkins node and trigger your java code on node.
Also you may like to use Gradle/Maven/TestNG as trigger and build.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. From what I have read, with Safari 10 the webdriver does not need to be set in the code. I did set this anyway to see if it would help and i was still getting the same error The tests are running fine locally, its running from jenkins is the issue. .The tests are run using testng

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error a couple of times. It seems to be a problem with the way you connect to jenkins. When you define a node in jenkins there is the option **Launch method**. Depending on the launch method you use behavour changes a little bit.

- Probably you are using the **Launch agents via SSH**, which allows you to permanently connect certain machine with certain Node. However, this method runs processes in the background. For some reason, safari does not work with background processes.
- Another method is the **Launch agent via Java Web Start**. With this option, each time you restart your machine you will have to manually connect it to the jenkins node through a Java applet. However with this method processes are launched on the front and lets you launch safari from jenkins.

I have not found a way to connect through SSH and launch safari correctly, nor I have seen any other solution.

Hope this is your issue!